# Hosting Angular2 apps on Drupal 8

Tags: angular, drupal-8

I would like to use Drupal 8 CMS and host my Angular2 apps under Drupal. I am not sure if this is possible, but would like to know if there are known best practises on integrating Angular2 with Drupal 8.
I imagine there are different approaches. I myself am thinking about just making my bootstrap page (index.html) available under a Drupal 8 path like http:///////index.html. (or index.php) ...?

Answer (score 0):

You could still implement Angular to serve certain pages but the best solution is to go headless, this literally means decoupling your application.

Drupal side, there is a API-First Drupal distribution to getting started: http://www.contentacms.org/

Here a short introduction about the headless concept: https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/what-is-headless-drupal/

Once you get familiar in how to expose your data through an API, you can definitely implement your own front end solution as for example Angular, React JS and so on.